# sorting algorithm to increase correlation with actual order

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have small (n= 50 to 100) "somewhat sorted" vectors e.g. their rank-order would correlate to the actual rank-order by around r=0.4
What sorting algorithm would require the least amount of pairwise comparisons to increase this correlation to 0.9?

Comment: What have you tried/researched so far? Share your ideas/findings.

Comment: It seems that insertion sort is best for sorting an almost sorted array to completion. I didn't find algorithm comparison for "almost-completion".

https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-best-sorting-algorithm-for-an-almost-sorted-array

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert specifically on approximate sorting algorithms, but Pearson correlation of permutations isn't really considered in the CS theory I've seen. My intuition is that a complicated algorithm with good asymptotic behavior won't scale down well to 50--100 elements, so the first thing I'd try would be [Shellsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort) but skip the smallest gaps.

Comment: I tried insertion, bubble and quick so far. Will try shell as well.

Comment: @SunWuKung I'd be very interested to know how well it works.

Comment: I found this one that I believe now is most relevant: https://michael.hahsler.net/SMU/CS8331/material/H-LUBC.html